# Apple 360 example

Tags: javascript, css, html, 360-degrees

Maybe all of you saw [Apple’s HTML5 showcase](http://www.apple.com/html5/). The thing is, they didn’t put anything downloadable online, am I right?

Has anyone found a 360 example like [theirs](http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/threesixty/) that we can download and use as is, instead of going through the Safari reference book?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the source code and download

http://lukedurrant.com/2011/08/apples-360-rotating-ipod-html-5-source-code-download/

Since the original poster answered his own question and then didn't leave the answer of where he got it from.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this:
http://www.apple.com/html5/

You can just right-click > 'view-source in safari to see what they are doing...

Comment: what a smart pants answer. I meant if they have some sample downloadable AS IS. not with tons of code and libraries...just THAT example..no worries i already found by myself.

Comment: @frank that's not a smartass answer.  HTML5 is html.  Staypuft's answer is completely valid.